# Achieving efficient condition based data mapping without a for loop?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table with > 18 mil rows (multiple events related to multiple objects) and I am trying to create a mapping column on whether an object has the same series of event  occurrence or not.

Example data frame (using data.table for efficiency):

`aa<-data.table(data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),`
 `val=c("a","a","b","a","c","c","c","a","b","c","a","b")))`

The object corresponds to the id column and value is the event occurrence associated with the event.

Desired outcome, where `noswitch` is my mapping column:

```
    id val noswitch
 1:  1   a       NA
 2:  1   a       NA
 3:  1   b       NA
 4:  1   a       NA
 5:  4   c     TRUE
 6:  4   c     TRUE
 7:  4   c     TRUE
 8:  5   a       NA
 9:  5   b       NA
10:  5   c       NA
11:  5   a       NA
12:  5   b       NA
```

*Only interested in marking where ALL events for an object have the same value*

Code that does the above using a for loop:

```
ids<-unique(aa$id)

aa$noswitch<-rep(NA,nrow(aa))

for ( i in 1: length(ids))
{
  if  ( length(unique(aa[id==ids[i]]$val))==1)  aa[id==ids[i]]$noswitch<-1
}
```

Considering the number of rows of my original df and the over 2 million objects , using the for loop will take **>5-6 days**.

Is there another  more efficient way to achieve this without splitting the data set and running some in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on the `data.table` package. The idea is to count the row numbers per `id` and `val`, and then check if the number is the same as the total row number per `id`.

```
library(data.table)

aa[, Count := .N, by = .(id, val)][
  , noswitch := Count == .N, by = id][
    , Count := NULL][]
#     id val noswitch
#  1:  1   a    FALSE
#  2:  1   a    FALSE
#  3:  1   b    FALSE
#  4:  1   a    FALSE
#  5:  4   c     TRUE
#  6:  4   c     TRUE
#  7:  4   c     TRUE
#  8:  5   a    FALSE
#  9:  5   b    FALSE
# 10:  5   c    FALSE
# 11:  5   a    FALSE
# 12:  5   b    FALSE
```

Comment: That's a great solution, the execution was a few seconds compared to days! Amazing . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also take advantage of `data.table::uniqueN`.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, noswitch := uniqueN(val) == .N, id]
```

I find this solution easier to read, but note that it is not as fast the first solution.